# Unable to install Redis extension in Docker php fpm-alpine image

Tags: docker, redis, alpine-linux

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.15
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk add libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS && pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so
```

I receive back this error during building process

**No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/redis"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this github issue: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1661 where someone had a similar issue in a different case. There are a couple of possible workarounds there.

Boils down to your connection possibly not being able to retrieve the package to you needing to do a couple of extra steps such as updating the channels before you can search for/install redis.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `pecl update-channels` before `pecl -o -f install redis`.

Already add `apk del $PHPIZE_DEPS` for cleanup.

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.15
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk add libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    apk del libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS && \
    pecl update-channels && \
    pecl install redis && \
    docker-php-ext-enable redis && \
    apk del $PHPIZE_DEPS
```

Answer (score 0):

Only replace `pecl install redis` to `pecl -o -f install redis`

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.15
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk add libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS && pecl -o -f install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue, each time it gives me a different error message

error: 'redis' does not exist or

error: 'xdebug' does not exist

I managed to solve it using this
https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1661#issuecomment-849813400

```
# add these 2 lines before pecl install solved my download/connection issue
RUN pear update-channels
RUN pecl update-channels

RUN pecl install redis xdebug mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis xdebug mongodb
```